# How do owl and rdfs property domain range work?

Tags: owl, ontology, rdfs, graphdb

I am trying to understand the semantics of rdfs domain and range.  Because I am from an object oriented background, I am struggling to understand the semantics and how to validate data against the rdfs statements.

Here is a sample file in turtle format:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix tmpl: <http://template.example.com/>
prefix data: <http://data.example.com/>

    tmpl:Thing a owl:Class.
    tmpl:Employment rdfs:subClassOf tmpl:TemporalThing.
    tmpl:Party rdfs:subClassOf tmpl:Thing.
    tmpl:Individual rdfs:subClassOf tmpl:Party.
    tmpl:Organisation rdfs:subClassOf tmpl:Party.
    tmpl:LimitedLiabilityCompany rdfs:subClassOf tmpl:Organisation.
    tmpl:hasCurrentEmployer a owl:ObjectProperty;
        rdfs:domain tmpl:Party;
        rdfs:range tmpl:Party.
    data:Simon a tmpl:Individual;
        skos:prefLabel "Simon S".
    data:PtyLtd a tmpl:LimitedLiabilityCompany.
    data:Simon tmpl:hasCurrentEmployer data:PtyLtd.

    tmpl:Animal a owl:Thing.
    data:Beans a tmpl:Animal.
    data:Simon tmpl:hasCurrentEmployer data:Beans.
```

I am using GRAPHDB as my test environment.  I would expect the last statement to fail with some sort of message because 'Beans' is an 'Animal' which is **not** a 'Party'.

Yet, GRAPHDB just accepts the statement.

Any ideas?

EDIT

Based on Stanislav's comment below: While An inference engine might not have a problem with this, we can use the domain and range for error checking in an application.

Comment: Where's the statement that an `Animal` is not a `Party`? Remember: [Open World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption). If you run the current knowledge base through a reasoner, it will infer that `Beans` is a `Party`. Also: do you have [inference](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/devhub/inference.html) configured on the database?

Comment: I thought that because Animal and Party are in two different class hierarchies that the reasoner would not regard them as equivalent.

Comment: OWL classes are only disjoint if there is a reason (i.e. a direct or inferred axiom) that makes them so. Given you current knowledge base, there's no such reason (yet).

Comment: If you want separate hierarchies to be disjoint, you have to (as a minimum) declare the roots to be disjoint.

Comment: @user2302244 in OWL, not inferring something doesn't mean that the negation holds! That's important to understand!

Comment: By way, you are right in some sense... On RDFS level, an application behaviour is rather unspecified. See [4. Using the Domain and Range vocabulary](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_domainrange). Please edit your question slightly, I'll upvote it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you misunderstood the semantics of domain and range.

```
P rdfs:domain D
P rdfs:range R
```

mean that if a statement `s P o` holds, then (with a reasoner running), it could be inferred that `s rdf:type D` and `o rdf:type R`.

Domain and range are never restrictions on the the property. That has to be clear.

To understand how things work, check for examplem [OWL direct semantics for object properties here](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/#Object_Property_Expression_Axioms).