# How to use 1 Object Property based on other ObjectProperty's assertion then make reasoning on individual in OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, rdfs, swrl

Classes

```
Member
Guest
```

Object properties

```
hasReferral (step 1)
hasVote (step 2)
hasApprove (step 3)
```

Individuals

```
A is a Member
B is a Member
C is a Guest



A hasReferral C
B hasVote C
so infer A hasApprove C
```

or

If B hasVote C Then A hasReferral C, So A hasApprove C

How to do this with OWL ?

I've tried

```
hasReferral
domain: Member
range: hasVote min 1 Guest
```

But it doesn't work.

When i apply `Member` as a domain to `hasVote`, it turns red :

[image]

I want to negative `A hasReferral C` when `Member` has not `hasVote` for C.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Let's start with the following: Why do you think that `hasReferral domain: Member`and `hasReferral range: hasVote min 1 Guest` imply `A hasApprove C` ?

Comment: Next, you said *"when i apply Member as a domain to hasVote, it turns red"* - this  indicates that the property is unsatisfiable, which means that you omitted some information here like e.g. the disjointness between some classes...

Comment: okay so the range doesn't work like that right?

Comment: can i use OWL make such inference ?

Comment: It's important that you understand what domain and range of a property mean. Do you do this?

Comment: And as I said in your last question, SWRL is the most straightforward way.

Comment: haha i have to read book again. domain and range can input expression on protege, what do they do exactly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397250/how-do-owl-and-rdfs-property-domain-range-work