# In OWL/protege, for a property how to define (domain: A and range: X) or (domain: B and range: Y)?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I've a property that has domain "A or B" and range "X or Y".

I want to say that

1. "when doamin is A, the range can only be X" or vice versa
2. "when doamin is B, the range can only be Y" or vice versa

Also these classes are **not** disjointed with each others. Hence I couldn't use some general class axiom to put restrictions.

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you aware that `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range` [aren’t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44410454/19579546) restrictions?

Comment: In addition to the comment, it's difficutl to model this in OWL, SWRL could be easier - but even then the negation in the conclusion would suffer from Open World Assumption. And those are just inference rules, not constraints

Comment: `A and (p some Thing) SubClassOf p only (X and not Y) ` would state that each individual belonging to `A` and having the property `p`, then the values will belong to `X` and not `Y`